# youtube api upload "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written"

Tags: asp.net, upload, youtube-api

I am using the youtube api to direct upload videos like this:

```
    YouTubeRequestSettings setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("devpa", key, "user", "pass");
    YouTubeRequest req = new YouTubeRequest(setting);

    Video ytv = new Video();
    ytv.Title = "test video1";
    ytv.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    ytv.Keywords = "test, dev";
    ytv.Description = "this is a test video";
    ytv.YouTubeEntry.Private = true;
    ytv.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(Server.MapPath("PATH"), "video/mp4");

    Video createdVideo = req.Upload(ytv);
```

But every time i get this error:

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written

Even though **i am uploading small videos with different extinctions (flv,mp4 ..etc) **, what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set timeout. Like ytv.TimeOut = 100000000;

Comment: @EmaadAli - Had to set it on the setting itself not the video, please add the comment to answer so i can accept, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set timeout. Like ytv.TimeOut = 100000000;

Answer (score 0):

Actually set the instance of

```
YouTubeRequestSettings.Timeout = [A LARGER NUMBER]
```

That's the setting you'll want to use.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others